# How do can I use a list as the values for a plotly table?

Tags: python, mysql, plotly

I am creating a page on an app that diosplays a users past 5 workouts from a database. So far I have the database querys set up so that they are working fine. I do not know how to get the data from these into the columns of the table.
Here is what I have at the moment:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import mysql.connector

from datetime import datetime
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost", # setting the host of the server to a local host
    user="tyler", # setting the user of the database to myself
    passwd="root", # giving the password to the databse
    database="FitnessApp") # accessing the fitness app database

mycursor = db.cursor() # set up a cursor which controls everything

account_number = 2

mycursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Workouts WHERE AccountNumber = '%s' LIMIT 5 """ % account_number)
user_workouts = []
for x in mycursor: # looping through mycursor
    user_workouts.append(x) # appending the user_details array
print(user_workouts)



fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['Workout', 'Time', 'Intensity', 'Calories']),
                 cells=list(values=user_workouts)
fig.show()

fig.write_image("table.png")
```

What I get from the mysql query is this:

```
[
 (2, '26/02/21', 'Run', 30, 265), 
 (2, '26/02/21', 'Run', 30, 265), 
 (2, '26/02/21', 'Cycle', 30, 565), 
 (2, '26/02/21', 'Swim', 30, 365), 
 (2, '26/02/21', 'Run', 30, 176)
]
```

Which is what I expected to happen.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. And `*` is not very useful for us.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you, I have changed it now to order by the date it was inputted with a limit of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your desired output resembles this:

[image]

If that's the case, and if what we're seeing in your example is indeed a list of tuples, you'll need to turn that list into a list of *lists* using:

```
lists = [list(elem) for elem in tuples]
```

And then treat that list as a matrix and transpos it using:

```
np.array(lists).T.tolist()
```

#### Complete code for data munging and table building:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tuples = [
         (2, '26/02/21', 'Run', 30, 265), 
         (2, '26/02/21', 'Run', 30, 265), 
         (2, '26/02/21', 'Cycle', 30, 565), 
         (2, '26/02/21', 'Swim', 30, 365), 
         (2, '26/02/21', 'Run', 30, 176)
    ]

# lists = [list(elem) for elem in tuples]
lists_t = np.array([list(elem) for elem in tuples]).T.tolist()

fig = go.Figure(go.Table(#header=dict(values=df.columns.to_list()),
                         cells=dict(values=[list(elem) for elem in lists_t])
                        )
                     )
fig.show()
```